# UICollectionViewCell change position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

[image]

By default, when you create a collection view , items are top and bottom margins are generated.

I want to move the cell position. (Center to bottom)
Is there any way to solve ?

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width / 2.2, collectionView.frame.size.height-60);
}
```

Comment: adding subview with required frame would be a good option.

Comment: @adnan Can you explain more ?

Comment: R u using AutoLayouts..! If yes...set Bottom space to superview for content..!

Comment: Where you move to your cell position.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

OK.
Change value in Collection view flow layout.